# AWS ACM, why s private certificate more expensive than public certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl, ssl-certificate

I must have missed something between public/private certificate.

In AWS ACM, public certificate are free, but private cert are not. I would have assumed it was the reverse.
Public certificate are generated by a globally trusted entity, while private certificate are self signed.
As far as I know, self managing private certificate is an easy task and while having a managed service is always useful, it is not adding lot of value.
At the contrary, self managing a public certificate, well is actually impossible since you need a trusted entity.

So why is public certificate in ACM free while private is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Private ACM certificates require provisioning a private certificate authority server. That's a big part of the price difference. Also, as you can see from [the Private CA documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/privateca/latest/userguide/PcaWelcome.html), the Private CA service:

> is for enterprise customers building a public key infrastructure (PKI) inside the AWS cloud and intended for private use within an organization

They built it for large enterprises, and priced it accordingly.

Contrast that with public SSL/TLS certificates, which quite a few other services were giving away for free, and AWS didn't really have a choice but to give those away for free as well.

---

If you just want free self-signed certificates, and you don't need a Certificate Authority server to validate those certificates against, then you can always just generate your own self-signed certs with a tool like `openssl`.

Comment: Ok I see, make total sense. Thank you !